# Transistors keep failing in dc motor controller

Tags: mosfet, motor, power-electronics, dc, driver

I feel like I'm a few steps away from becoming famous on this site with this controller but it's literally been years and I've went way too far to give up on it now..

Here is my schematic:

[image]

It uses N channel MOSFETs only and a couple of relays to reverse direction.

My motor is brushed, rated at 36V 28A. I have measured it's resistance at 0.25Ohm which gives about 150A stall current.

When I instantly apply 5V at JP1's pin 2 (a.k.a. 100% pwm) the transistor fails. How I know is, when I remove the 5V the motor continues spinning and when I desolder the transistor and measure between source and drain in diode mode I get about 0.02V where a good transistor of the same type measures 0.45V. This transistor (Q1, Q2) is rated at more than the motor's stall current as continuous ([datasheet](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irfp3206pbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a401535628d64a1ff0)), so it definitely should not fail like this?

Things to consider:

For my tests I tried with only a single transistor (Q1) at a time, I burned through 2 and I stopped as these are not so cheap.
For R5 I used a piece of wire, I added resistor footprints in case I need them.
For C1 I'm not exactly sure what value I'm using, I grabbed the biggest ceramic capacitor from my nano bag so it might be in the hundreds of nF but I doubt that's what could be causing the transistor to fail?

Yet again, why are my transistors failing?

Comment: How does the 12V and gate voltage look with respect to ground just before they fail?

Comment: @winny unfortunately I don't have a scope, this is still just a hobby for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before the MOSFETs initially start to turn on, the 36 volt supply is across the MOSFET and, at some point, the voltage across the MOSFET drops to about 18 volts as it turns on. It could be argued that in this short period of time the motor is still in a stall condition i.e. looking like 0.25 Ω. So, when the MOSFET and motor each have 18 volts across them (totalling 36 volts i.e. the supply), in that particular point in time 72 amps are flowing into the MOSFET and its drain-source voltage is 18 volts.

Here's the safe operating curve from the [datasheet](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IRFP3206-DataSheet-v01_01-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a401535628d64a1ff0): -

[image]

I've marked a blue circle where 72 amps crosses 18 volts. This tells me that anything longer than maybe 300 μs in this region is going to spell disaster for the MOSFET.

What you have to do is figure out how long the motor takes to start spinning on application of a hard supply voltage from the MOSFET or if there is any way that your gate drive control voltage is lingering in a bad area that can make the MOSFET destroy itself. Of course if your circuit board layout is poor then this could be a bigger reason for the MOSFET destruction.

I've ignored that fact that there are two MOSFETs in parallel because one will always switch on before the other.

Comment: So it would be practically impossible to give the motor "full throttle" through the mosfet from a "stand still" unless I get a massively oversized (as if this one already isn't) transistor? This doesn't seem right..

Comment: That sounds reasonable so, maybe use pulse width modulation  to ramp up the speed over (say) half a second?

Comment: Well, that *might* work with no load, but when loaded the motor will definitely not reach full speed in half or even one second. Won't I end up having too much current running for longer than safe again by increasing pulse width without feedback?

Comment: You have to be cautious in the control and be pragmatic in how you increase the duty cycle of the pulse width modulation. The bottom line is that you might need to sense current and adjust the duty cycle accordingly @php_nub_qq

Comment: Bummer. But this is not the case with commercial drivers (even 30$ ebay ones), or so I think..

Comment: I wouldn't rely on peebay stuff at all. No data sheets, very little specs, nothing set in stone, no apparent quality system to build, no real links to original manufacturer, no confidence!